# ini_set() is not blocked, yet I get "Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons"

Tags: php, magento

I've been banging my head for hours for this strange issue. My Magento shows me the error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons 
/path/to/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php 
on line 598
```

Here's what line 598 looks like:

```
598: $result = ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
```

Here comes the strange part. When I add following just above this line 598:

```
597: echo ini_get('disable_functions');die;
598: $result = ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
```

I get this:

```
passthru,shell_exec,system
```

There's no **ini_set** in this list of disabled functions, yet somehow Magento manages to consider it blocked for "Security Reasons"...

I have checked all possible PHP configurations on the server. `ini_set()` is NOT blocked anywhere. This is giving me a tough time.

What's going on?

---

**Edit 1**

I created a test script, outside Magento with the following:

```
var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', 'Off'));
var_dump(ini_get('display_errors') );
```

Here's what I get whatever ini value I set...

```
NULL string(0) ""
```

Comment: What environment is this being run in? You can check which php.ini file is being used using this function: `var_dump( get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path') );`

Comment: Observing `phpinfo()` output might be usefull.

Comment: @JacobMulquin I checked, and in that php.ini, the `disable_functions` is blank...

Comment: Hmm that's bizarre. What happens if you make a test script with `ini_set` in the same environment, which doesn't touch Magento code

Comment: @Jared I guess `ini_get()` should be taking value from whatever config file is loaded...

Comment: @arxoft more like `ini_get()` takes the current effective value. Does the `phpinfo()` show something relevant?

Comment: Is it triggering the warning but still setting the configuration value anyway?

Comment: @JacobMulquin I created test script (see Edit 1 in the question above). Looks like `ini_set` or `ini_get` both are not working. `phpinfo()` just returns NULL...

Comment: Hmm is `ini_get` working on a common value that you had not set previously? e.g. `ini_get('short_open_tag')`? This is a really strange problem.

Comment: Ask your server admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting provider has enabled some kind of security measures beyond those built into PHP.

My first guess was the delightfully named [Snuffleupagus](https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/). Among many other things, it features [comprehensive control of ini settings](https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/config.html#ini-settings-protection) and the ability to block function calls in a very granular way. On the other hand, I don't see anything in there about disabling phpinfo(), which you said didn't display anything; and your error message suggests the function was converted to a no-op with a Warning, rather than an error. (Which Magento then promoted to an exception.)

Either way, there's very likely nothing you can do about it, other than contact your hosting provider.